# JFileChooser loses last file path

Tags: java, swing, path, jfilechooser

I have a JFileChooser that selects a file from directory (I use openCSV) and populates data into a JTable.

```
public class SelectFileButtonHandler{
//...
public SelectFileButtonHandler(FileReaderWindow fileReaderWindow) {
    this.fileReaderWindow = fileReaderWindow;
    this.fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    this.fileHandler = new FileHandler();
}

public boolean isFileSelected(){ return (this.result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION); }

/**
 * returns the file's absolute path in a String object
 * @return String
 */
public String getCurrentFilePath(){return this.currentFilePath;}

public String getFileType(){
    return getFileName().substring(getFileName().lastIndexOf("."), getFileName().length());
}

public String getLastFilePath(){return this.lastFilePath;}

/**
 * Sets the file by defining the path
 * @param path 
 */
public void setFile(String path){this.file = new File(path);}

public void handleCommand() {
    this.fileHandler.readFile();
    this.fileReaderWindow.setRowData(fileHandler.getFileData());
    this.fileReaderWindow.setDataDemoTable(fileReaderWindow.getRowData());
    this.fileReaderWindow.setDataDemoTableC2(fileReaderWindow.getRowData());
    this.fileHandler.closeFile();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    try{
        if(event.getActionCommand().equalsIgnoreCase("Προσθήκη αρχείου")){
            openFileDialog();
            if(isFileSelected()){
                setCurrentFilePath(this.fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                setLastFilePath(getCurrentFilePath());
                this.fileHandler.openFile(getCurrentFilePath());
                handleCommand();
            }
        }
        else {
            nextInChain.actionPerformed(event);
        }   
    }
    catch(Exception exception){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exception.getMessage(), null, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public void openFileDialog(){
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("txt", "txt", "txt");
    this.fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    this.result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null); 
}

public void setCurrentFilePath(String currentFilePath){this.currentFilePath = currentFilePath;}
public void setLastFilePath(String lastFilePath){this.lastFilePath = lastFilePath;}
}
```

FileHandler.java

```
public class FileHandler{

 /**
 * Opens file located to the specific path
 * Path is absolute
 * @param path 
 */
public void openFile(String path) {setFileInputStream(path);}

/**
 * Reads data from file. 
 * Data are separated by split character selected by combo box.
 */
public void readFile() {
    try {
        setUTF8_CHARSET();
        setInputStreamReader(getFileInputStream(), getUTF8_CHARSET());
        setCSVReader(getInputStreamReader(),      this.fileReaderWindow.getSplitChoose().getSelectedItem().toString().charAt(0));
        setFileData(getCSVReader().readAll());
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch(java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError err){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err.toString(), null, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
    }
}

public void setCSVReader(InputStreamReader inputStreamReader, char separator){
    this.csvReader = new CSVReader(inputStreamReader, separator);
}

public void setFileData(List<String[]> fileData){this.fileData = fileData;}

public void setFileInputStream(String path){
     try{
        this.fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(path); 
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException exception){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Το αρχείο δε βρέθηκε στο δίσκο.\nΠαρακαλώ, ξαναπροσπαθήστε.", null, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public void setInputStreamReader(FileInputStream fileInputStream, CharsetDecoder UTF8_CHARSET){
    this.inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, UTF8_CHARSET);
}

}
```

My problem is, when I try to call getLastFilePath from another class, I get null instead of path

```
public class SplitChooseComboHandler implements ItemListener{
private FileReaderWindow fileReaderWindow;
private FileHandler fileHandler;
private SelectFileButtonHandler selectFileButtonHandler;

@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
   if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
      this.fileReaderWindow = new FileReaderWindow();
      this.selectFileButtonHandler = new SelectFileButtonHandler(fileReaderWindow);
      this.fileHandler.openFile(selectFileButtonHandler.getLastFilePath());
      this.selectFileButtonHandler.handleCommand();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "file path is: " + this.selectFileButtonHandler.getLastFilePath(), null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
   }
}
}
```

Could someone explain why is this happening? Thank you in advance

Comment: You do not set it. In `itemStateChanged` you create a new instance of the `SelectFileButtonHandler`. Its Field "lastFilePath" is uninitialized. Maybe you should retrieve (and write) that path from some Application-wide datamodel or keep a static instance of the FileChooser in the app.

Comment: static like private static or public static?Is access type important here?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

have file lastFilePath = new File
and in your File Handler have

```
    public static void LastFile{
        lastFilePath = (File)selectFileButtonHandler.getLastFilePath();
    }
```

and in your splitChooseComboHandler
replace the selectFileButtonHandler.getLastFilePath() with LastFilePath
check if that works haha

Comment: _have file lastFilePath = new File_ could you please explain to me where should I have it? In SelectFileButtonHandler or inside FileHandler?

Comment: inside filehandler have it static and make sure to call the LastFile() before you pull the the fileHandler.lastFilePath

Comment: I get "incombatible types String cannot be converted to File" and "non-static variable selectFileButtonHandler cannot be referrenced from a static context"

Comment: looking at it a bit closer are you trying to call getlastFilePath or setLastFilePath because i cannot find any getlastFilePath

Comment: `static` is very rarely a solution

Comment: I am calling getLastFilePath() and it does exist inside selectFileButtonHandler

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at you code...

```
// Create a new instance of SelectFileButtonHandler
this.selectFileButtonHandler = new SelectFileButtonHandler(fileReaderWindow);
this.fileHandler.openFile(selectFileButtonHandler.getLastFilePath());
```

At the time of calling `getLastFilePath`, the value `lastFilePath` is `null`

The value of `lastFilePath` is only changed by the `setLastFilePath` method, but this is only called by the `actionPerformed` method in `SelectFileButtonHandler`.

This means when the value `path` value is passed to the `setFileInputStream` method in `FileHandler`, it is `null`...

You could take into account for the possibility of the `lastFilePath` been `null` and provide a default value, like the user's home directory for example...

Comment: So, I guess it's unecessairy to have 2 String constants for current and last file path as well...

Comment: To be honest, I didn't dig through your code that deeply, but I would tend to agree, the concept doesn't make much sense...